# distance calculation between two tables of lat/lon

Tags: mysql, performance, select, subquery, mariadb

I have the following two tables

### cities

id,lat,lon

### mountains

id,latitude,longitude

```
SELECT cities.id, 
    (SELECT id FROM mountains 
    WHERE SQRT(POW(69.1 * ( latitude -  cities.lat ) , 2 ) + 
    POW( 69.1 * (cities.lon - longitude ) * 
    COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) )<20 LIMIT 1) as mountain_id 
FROM cities
```

(Query took 0.5060 seconds.)

*I've removed some parts of the query (e.g. order by, where) for the complexity's sake. However it doesn't affect the execution time really.*

The **EXPLAIN** below.

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY cities ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 478379
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY mountains ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 15645 Using where
```

Using the SELECT itself is not my problem but when I try to use the given result... e.g.

```
id mountain_id 

588437 NULL
588993 4269
589014 4201
589021 4213
589036 4952
589052 7625
589113 9235
589125 NULL
589176 1184
589210 4317
```

...to UPDATE a table everything gets awfully slow. I tried pretty much everything that I know of. I do know that a dependent sub-query isn't optimal but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Is there any way to improve my query. Maybe changing it into a JOIN?

The 2 tables itself have nothing really in common except latitude and longitude which are different and are only brought into relation when using calculations.

Spatial distance search (km,miles) in MariaDB seems not to be available yet.

Comment: It looks like you want all pairs of (cities / mountains) that lie within 20 statute miles of one another. Is that correct?

Comment: That's what it does right now. The 20 miles are just there to reduce the amount of results. When I add the order by distance (which I have left out for now for complexity's sake) it gives me the closest match from table1 to table2.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to making this sort of operation fast is to avoid doing all that computation on every possible pair of lat/lon points. To do that you should incorporate a bounding-box operation.

Let's start by using a JOIN.  In pseudocode, you want something like this, but it doesn't matter if you catch a few extra pairs, as long as they are further apart than the others.

```
    SELECT c.city_id, m.mountain_id
      FROM cities c
      JOIN mountains m ON distance_in_miles(c, m) < 20
```

So we need to figure out how to make that ON clause fast -- make it use indexes rather than rambling around all the cities and mountains (with apologies to Woody Guthrie).

Let's try this for the ON clause. It searches within square bounding boxes of +/- 20 miles for nearby pairs.

```
    SELECT c.city_id, m.mountain_id
      FROM cities c
      JOIN mountains m
                  ON m.lat BETWEEN c.lat - (20.0 / 69.0)
                               AND c.lat + (20.0 / 69.0)
                 AND  m.lon BETWEEN c.lon - (20.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(c.lat))))
                                AND c.lon + (20.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(c.lat))))
```

In this query, `20.0` is the comparison limit radius, and `69.0` is the constant defining statute miles per degree of latitude.

Then, put compound indexes on `(lat, lon, id)` on both tables, and your `JOIN` operation will be able to use index range scans to make the query more efficient.

Finally, you can augment that query with these sorts of clauses, in pseudocode

```
       ORDER BY  dist_in_miles (c,m) ASC
          LIMIT  1
```

Here you actually need to use a distance formula. The cartesian-distance formula in your question is an approximation that works tolerably well unless you're near the pole. You may want to use a great circle formula instead. Those are called spherical cosine law, haversine, or Vincenty formulas.

Comment: Thanks in advance! I tried your approach. It seems much slower for now but I haven't added all the filters. How do I filter the result to get one result per city_id? The LIMIT affects the whole resultset. In the end I would like to see a list as seen in my original posting where I get one city_id and one mountain_id.